# Hot reload in Flutter acts like hot restart

Tags: flutter, reload, restart

Every time I save, my app goes all the way back to the sign up screen rather than updating the screen I'm on with hot reload.

Comment: On web?  that's expected.  Otherwise, it might just be something wrong with your global state, which doesn't get re-initialized on a hot-reload.